# Como hago para que me retorne el valor en numero y no la palabra Range?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

Intento que me retorne un numero para hacer operaciones pero me da la palabra Range. 
Como hago para que me devuelva el valor numérico

```js
function myFunction() {
  var sheetcoil = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet1 = 'prueba'
  var datos = sheetcoil.getSheetByName(sheet1);
  var coil = datos.getRange(1,1);
  Logger.log(coil);
  var coil1 = datos.getRange(2,2).setValue(coil)
}
```

?
Sheet: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ujmZ.png
Reporte: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wmrd3.png

Answer (score 1):

Debes usar `getValue()` / `getDisplayValue()`

El primero te devolverá un valor de tipo número, texto o fecha.

El segundo te devolverá un valor de tipo texto.

Por ejemplo, reemplaza

```
Logger.log(coil);
```

Por

```
Logger.log(coil.getValue());
```

Comment: Lo hago pero me sale el siguiente error: Exception: Los parámetros (number,number) no coinciden con la firma de método de SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getActiveCell. (línea 7, archivo "Código")
`function myFunction() {
  var sheetcoil = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet1 = 'prueba'
  var datos = sheetcoil.getSheetByName(sheet1);
  var coil = datos.getRange(1,1)
  Logger.log(coil.getValue())
  var coil1 = datos.getActiveCell(2,2).getValue(coil)
}`

Comment: @Francisco el error en cuestión no tiene que ver con lo que te sugerí, de hecho el código que incluyes en el comentario incluye otros cambios por lo que te sugiero publicar un nueva pregunta.